# How to filter with multiple conditions based on elements text in Cypress?

Tags: jquery, typescript, cypress

Given this HTML, I want to yield the .row element based on code = 002 and ref = 001

```
<div class="row">
    <span class="code">001</span>
    <span class="ref">002</span>
    <label>Some Label</label>   
</div>
<div class="row">
    <span class="code">002</span>
    <span class="ref">002</span>
    <label>Another label</label>    
</div>
<div class="row">
    <span class="code">002</span>
    <span class="ref">001</span>
    <label>Something</label>    
</div>
```

I would have thought the following should work but it doesnt filter anything

```
cy.get('.row').filter(`span.code:contains("002")span.ref:contains("001")`)
```

Even with one condition it seems to not work. Any idea what Im doing wrong?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Maybe this can guide you https://jsfiddle.net/hsdvfjwt/

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen indeed it has! Thanks a lot. I'll copy the solution

Answer (score 4):

As someone suggested in the comment I used a function that retrieve elements with jQuery. This is working

```
cy.get('.row').filter((i, $el) => {
        return Cypress.$($el).find('span.code:contains("002")').length > 0
          && Cypress.$($el).find('span.ref:contains("001")').length > 0;
      })
```